# How to push to AWS EC2 Service Container from a specific git branch (ie 'staging')

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I'm completely new to AWS, EC2, and the Service Container, but I did manage to successfully push my sinatra application with docker fairly easily following this guide here:

http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-to-deploy-a-sinatra-app-in-docker-to-amazon-s-ec2-container-service/

Now I have 2 service containers, one for production and one for staging. My original hypothesis was that I could push to the staging container from the git staging branch and to the production container from the git production branch from my local machine. When I made a change on the staging branch and pushed the image to the staging container the staging site did not reflect the new changes (I did clear cache in the browser).

**Q1:** Does EC2 SC automatically accept the master branch regardless of which branch the project is pushed from?

**Q2:** What is the simplest way to accomplish staging and production servers with AWS (perhaps not SC, perhaps beanstalk?).

Note: Not using Heroku since the company contracting me wants all their systems on AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to the AWS console, and got to your EC2 Instances

Select your instance (for example you-app-staging) and right-click > Instance State > Reboot

After a few minutes the instance will reboot and you will see the changes to that instance.

**A1:** no, you're pushing a image then AWS takes that image and hits play so if you build the image in the branch and deploy it from that branch, you will see the branch pushed

**A2:** Maybe over complicated solution with the service containers, now things work as expected

Comment: You could take a look at AWS CodePipeline https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continuous-deployment-to-amazon-ecs-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codebuild-amazon-ecr-and-aws-cloudformation/